# Calculate statistics on subset of a dataframe based on values in dataframe (latitude and longitude)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, distance, latitude-longitude

I am looking to calculate summary statistics on subsets of a dataframe but related to a specific values within the row.

For example, I have a dataframe that has latitude and longitude and number of people.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': [40.991919 , 40.992001 , 40.991602, 40.989903, 40.987759],
                   'longitude': [-106.049469, -106.048812, -106.048904, -106.049907, -106.048840],
                   'people': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I want to know the total people within .05 miles from each row. This can be easily created with a loop, but as the space starts to increase this becomes unusable.

Current/Sample:

```
from geopy.distance import distance

def distance_calc (row, focus_lat, focus_long):
    start = (row['latitude'], row['longitude'])
    stop = (focus_lat, focus_long)
    return distance(start, stop).miles

df['total_people_within_05'] = 0
df['total_rows_within_05'] = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    focus_lat = df['latitude'][index]
    focus_long = df['longitude'][index]
    new_df = df.copy()
    new_df['distance'] = new_df.apply (lambda row: (distance_calc(row, focus_lat, focus_long)),axis=1)
    df.at[index, 'total_people_within_05'] = new_df.loc[new_df.distance<=.05]['people'].sum()
    df.at[index, 'total_rows_within_05'] = new_df.loc[new_df.distance<=.05].shape[0]
```

Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cartesian product to itself to get all combinations.  This will be expensive on larger datasets.  This generates N^2 rows,  so in this case 25 rows
- calculate distance on each of these combinations
- filter `query()` to distances required
- `groupby()` to get total number of people.  Also generate a `list` of *indexes* included in total for helping with transparency
- finally `join()` this back together and you have what you want

```
import geopy.distance as gd

df = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': [40.991919 , 40.992001 , 40.991602, 40.989903, 40.987759],
                   'longitude': [-106.049469, -106.048812, -106.048904, -106.049907, -106.048840],
                   'people': [1,2,3,4,5]})

df = df.join((df.reset_index().assign(foo=1).merge(df.reset_index().assign(foo=1), on="foo")
 .assign(distance=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: gd.distance((r.latitude_x,r.longitude_x),
                                                                 (r.latitude_y,r.longitude_y)).miles, axis=1))
 .query("distance<=0.05")
 .rename(columns={"people_y":"nearby"})
 .groupby("index_x").agg({"nearby":"sum","index_y":lambda x: list(x)})
))

print(df.to_markdown())
```

|  | latitude | longitude | people | nearby | index_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40.9919 | -106.049 | 1 | 6 | [0, 1, 2] |
| 1 | 40.992 | -106.049 | 2 | 6 | [0, 1, 2] |
| 2 | 40.9916 | -106.049 | 3 | 6 | [0, 1, 2] |
| 3 | 40.9899 | -106.05 | 4 | 4 | [3] |
| 4 | 40.9878 | -106.049 | 5 | 5 | [4] |

### Update - use combinations instead of Cartesian product

It's been bugging me that a Cartesian product is a huge overhead,  when all that is required is to calculate distances between valid combinations

- make use of `itertools.combinations()` to make a list of valid combinations of indexes
- calculate distances between this minimum set
- filter down to only distances we're interested in
- now build permutations of this smaller set to provide a simple join to actual data
- join and aggregate

```
# get distances between all valid combinations
dfd = (pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(df.index, 2)))
 .merge(df, left_on=0, right_index=True)
 .merge(df, left_on=1, right_index=True, suffixes=("_0","_1"))
 .assign(distance=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: gd.distance((r.latitude_0,r.longitude_0),
                                                                 (r.latitude_1,r.longitude_1)).miles, axis=1))
 .loc[:,[0,1,"distance"]]
 # filter down to close proximities
 .query("distance <= 0.05")
)

# build all valid permuations of close by combinations
dfnppl = (pd.DataFrame(itertools.permutations(pd.concat([dfd[0],dfd[1]]).unique(), 2))
 .merge(df.loc[:,"people"], left_on=1, right_index=True)
)

# bring it all together
df = (df.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":0}).merge(dfnppl, on=0, suffixes=("","_near"), how="left")
 .groupby(0).agg({**{c:"first" for c in df.columns}, **{"people_near":"sum"}})
)
```

| 0 | latitude | longitude | people | people_near |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40.9919 | -106.049 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 40.992 | -106.049 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 40.9916 | -106.049 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 40.9899 | -106.05 | 4 | 0 |
| 4 | 40.9878 | -106.049 | 5 | 0 |